# Chrome Dev Tools "Find" Scope: Search through Resources (scripts, stylesheets, etc)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've often used the Find `CTRL/CMD + F` to find something in particular.  In the Chrome Dev Tools, on my home computer, all 3 scopes work:

- Rendered Content (outside of Chrome Dev Tools, CTRL/CMD + F while focused on the viewport)
- Chrome Dev Tools > Elements tab (search through raw source, excluding external files)
- Chrome Dev Tools > Resources tab (search through external files)

On this computer at work, pressing `CMD+F` (its a Mac) only works in the first 2 scopes listed above, and I can't seem to get the menu to appear on the Resources tab to search through the external resources.

Any suggestions?  Maybe this is just a nuance between Mac and Windows versions?

```
Chrome: Version 32.0.1700.77
OS X: Version 10.8.4
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On version 32x you may search from the resources tab by following these steps:

1. Open Devtools
2. Select the resources tab
3. Press the escape key
4. Select the "Search" tab from the console sub-panel
5. Enter your search criteria in the search box (see image below)
6. Press the Enter key

[image]

Comment: Nice.  Not sure why they hid it.  I'm pretty sure CMD+F used to work from the Resource panel.  Anyway, that'll do, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

[Hotkeys](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/L6rshpAss2c/fmDCf2tUHlgJ) for [Ethan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21341085/241211), if developer tools is open:

- Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>